# How to use gson to convert json data to java object?

Tags: java, gson

I have a `json` string. I want to convert it to java object. My entity class is `Deneme.java`.

`Result` variable stores `json` string. How can I make this process?

I get an error: `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY`

Data coming from the server is,

```
 {"games":
       [   
            {"game":"Football","probability":0.74656546},
            {"game":"Football","probability":0.23432424},
            {"game":"Football","probability":0.2342342343}
       ]
 }
```

`Deneme.java` is,

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import org.json.JSONArray;

import java.util.List;

public class Deneme {

    private List<JsonObject> matches;

    public List<JsonObject> getMatches() {
        return matches;
    }

    public void setMatches(List<JsonObject> matches) {
        this.matches = matches;
    }
}
```

My code is:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Deneme obj = gson.fromJson(result, Deneme.class);
```

Comment: what is in result , paste the full code of conversion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current structure you could use something like :

```
    public class Deneme {

        private List<JsonObject> games;

        public List<JsonObject> getMatches() {
            return games;
        }

        public void setMatches(List<JsonObject> games) {
            this.games = games;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Deneme deneme = new Gson().fromJson(json, Deneme.class);

        deneme.getMatches().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

You should change `private List<JsonObject> matches` to `private List<JsonObject> games`.

The output is :

```
{"game":"Football","probability":0.74656546}
{"game":"Football","probability":0.23432424}
{"game":"Football","probability":0.2342342343}
```

I think that in your case it could be better to create class `Game` and store list of `Game` objects inside your `Deneme` class, because now you are just storing `JsonObject`'s.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have same name when you are converting to `Deneme`

Change,

```
private List<JsonObject> matches;
```

To,

`private List<JsonObject> games;`

Comment: I get error: Incompatible types .Required Deneme but 'fromjson' but inferred to T. No instances of type variables exist